# Calcular valores em sub array [PHP]

Tags: php, json, array, foreach, slimframework

> Tenho um array com items, e cada com um sub-array aonde temos os valores a ser somado, estou tentando fazer com que cada sub-array tenha sua soma retornada, e  exiba o seguinte resultado..

```js
//Esse seria a forma correta do retorno da soma
{
    "item-a": 50.5,
    "item-b": 70.5
}
```

No entanto está me retornando da seguinte forma..

```js
/*
O primeiro 'item-a' até trás o resultado exato, já o segundo 'item-b'
soma o valor anterior com o valor que deveria ser aplicado ali. (50.5 + 70.5 = 121)
*/
{
    "item-a": 50.5,
    "item-b": 121
}
```

Esse é o código do qual estou procurando a solução..

```php
$items = array(
    'item-a' => [
        //valores a ser somado
        '1' => 25.5,
        '2' => 25.0
    ],
    'item-b' => [
        //valores a ser somado
        '1' => 30.5,
        '2' => 40.0
    ]
);

$valor = array();
//array items
foreach($items as $key => $res)
{
    //sub-array com valores do item
    foreach($res as $k => $val)
    {
        //somar
        $somar += $val;
        //retornar valor somado a cada item
        $valor[$key] = $somar;
    }
}
//imprimir array
return json_encode($valor, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa simples alteração resolve seu problema

```
$valor = array();
//array items
foreach($items as $key => $res)
{
    //sub-array com valores do item
    foreach($res as $k => $val)
    {
        //retornar valor somado a cada item
        isset($valor[$key]) ? $valor[$key] += $val : $valor[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Isso acontece porque você não zerou a variável $soma (que é desnecessária btw) na iteração do primeiro loop

Answer (score 1):

O PHP fornece um conjunto nativo de funções para se trabalhar com arrays, são os [Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).
Array Functions permitem acessar e manipular arrays e são suportados tanto arrays simples e multi-dimensionais.

Para sua pergunta vamos usar duas funções a [`array_sum ( array $array ) : number`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) que retorna o somatório dos elementos de um array e [`array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 \[, array $... \] ) : array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) que aplica uma determinada função a todos os elementos de um array ou grupo de array, grupo cujo a quantidade deve ser a mesma que a quantidade de parâmetros aceitos passada como callback para `map_array`.

A lógica desse exemplo é usar a função `array_map` para aplicar `array_sum` nos elementos de `$items`(`$item-a` e `$item-b`)

```
<?php

  $items = array(
    'item-a' => [
        //valores a ser somado
        '1' => 25.5,
        '2' => 25.0
    ],
    'item-b' => [
        //valores a ser somado
        '1' => 30.5,
        '2' => 40.0
    ]
  );


// Aplica a função array_sum aos arrays que compõe $items
$resultado = array_map('array_sum', $items);


// Exibe o resultado
print_r( json_encode( $resultado, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ));
?>
```

O resultado é:

```
{ "item-a": 50.5, "item-b": 70.5 }
```

Answer (score 0):

O único problema que estou vendo é que você não está iniciando a variável `$somar`.

Essa variável deveria receber o valor 0 no inicio de cada loop, dessa forma:

```
foreach($items as $key => $res)
{
    $somar = 0;
    //sub-array com valores do item
    foreach($res as $k => $val)
    {
        //somar
        $somar += $val;
        //retornar valor somado a cada item
        $valor[$key] = $somar;
    }
}
```